# How do I script brute forcing password to a WiFi with nmcli?

Tags: nmcli

The following script is meant look for the right password in the file `list-of-pwds`
in order to connect to a WiFi.
Once it finds the right password, it is meant not to look
anymore for the password.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

nmcli d wifi list

echo "Give me the SSID."
read ssid

if [[ -f $HOME/list-of-pwds ]]; then
    :
else
    >>$HOME/list-of-pwds
fi

echo -e "Place the passwords in $HOME/list-of-pwds.\nPress 'y' when ready to proceed?[Y/n]"
read proceed

if [[ "${proceed}" == 'y' ]]; then
  
      while IFS="" read -u 7 -r l || [[ -n "${l}" ]]; do    
      nmcli connection add type wifi ifname wlp3s0 ssid "${ssid}" con-name "${ssid}" +802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt WPA-PSK +802-11-wireless-security.psk "${l}"
      if [[ "${?}" -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "Found password for  ${ssid}: ${l}."
        break
      fi
    done 7<$HOME/list-of-pwds    
  
fi

#nmcli con show --active seems to return always 0 irrespectively on the connection status
#but nmcli con show --active|grep whatever returns 0 only when there is an active connection
```

`list-of-pwds` looks like this:

```
ana
game
bondage
domination
submission
masochism
thecorrrectPassword
tordfasre
```

When the correct password is not in the first line of
`list-of-pwds` I get the following output:

```
Error: Failed to add 'net' connection: 802-11-wireless-security.psk: property is invalid
Error: Failed to add 'net' connection: 802-11-wireless-security.psk: property is invalid
Error: Failed to add 'net' connection: 802-11-wireless-security.psk: property is invalid
Connection 'net' (66ab5db1-a662-43a0-bfbe-ee353a7e14d6) successfully added.
Found password for  net: domination.
```

where `net` is the ssid.
The security of my WiFi is WPA2. When the password is of the right length but is not correct,  [a popup
asking for the password shows up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1148947/prevent-supress-showing-popup-of-wifi-connection-asking-for-password-on-terminal). Such popup does not appear when the script
comes across the correct password, e.g. `domination` is not the correct password although it is of the right length (the popup shows up),
`thecorrrectPassword` is the right password (the popup does not show up).  It is this popup that made me replace `nmcli d wifi connect "${ssid}" password "${l}"`
with `nmcli connection add type wifi ifname wlp3s0 ssid "${ssid}" con-name "${ssid}" +802-11-wireless-security.key-mgmt WPA-PSK +802-11-wireless-security.psk "${l}"`
but the issue still remains.

Following the hint of @tripleee, I've tried passing the file with passwords as a command-line argument, which I modified so that it looks like so:

```
802-11-wireless-security.psk:ana
802-11-wireless-security.psk:game
802-11-wireless-security.psk:bondage
802-11-wireless-security.psk:domination
802-11-wireless-security.psk:submission
802-11-wireless-security.psk:masochism
802-11-wireless-security.psk:thecorrectPassword
802-11-wireless-security.psk:torture
```

with a script rewritten:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash


nmcli d wifi list

echo "Give me the SSID."
read ssid

if [[ -f $HOME/list-of-pwds ]]; then
    :
else
    >>$HOME/list-of-pwds
fi

echo -e "Place the passwords in $HOME/list-of-pwds.\nReady to proceed?[Y/n]"
read proceed

if [[ "${proceed}" == 'y' ]]; then
  nmcli con add type wifi con-name "${ssid}" ssid "${ssid}"
  nmcli con mod "${ssid}" wifi-sec.key-mgmt wpa-psk
  nmcli connection up "${ssid}" ifname wlp3s0 passwd-file "$HOME/list-of-pwds"
fi
```

I get the popup asking for the authentication and the following stdout:

```
Connection 'net' (dcaab1be-4d54-49f6-ac3b-30bc153806ae) successfully added.
Error: Connection activation failed: Secrets were required, but not provided
Hint: use 'journalctl -xe NM_CONNECTION=dcaab1be-4d54-49f6-ac3b-30bc153806ae + NM_DEVICE=wlp3s0' to get more details.
```

I am aware that scripting `nmcli` [is unlikely to make for a good brute forcing tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63619312/how-to-brute-force-a-wifi-password).
That said, I want to know whether it is doable to rewrite my script
so that it behaves similarly to brute forcing tools.
Is the issue distribution specific (I'm on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS)?

Comment: Tangentially, [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern) Perhaps a better design would be to pass in the SSID and the file of password as command-line arguments.

Comment: @tripleee I've tried passing the said file as you suggested and described how I failed in doing so in the question which I've just modified in response to your comment.